# How do I split a dataframe column that contains strings

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions, explode

I am using spark 2.2 and 
I am trying to read a dataset from a tsv file like the following in pyspark:

```
    student_id subjects result
    "1001" "[physics, chemistry]" "pass"
    "1001" "[biology, math]" "fail"
    "1002" "[economics]" "pass"
    "1002" "[physics, chemistry]" "fail"
```

And I want the following kind of result:

```
    student_id subject result
    "1001" "physics" "pass"
    "1001" "chemistry" "pass"
    "1001" "biology" "fail"
    "1001" "math" "fail"
    "1002" "economics" "pass"
    "1002" "physics" "fail"
    "1002" "chemistry" "fail"
```

I did the following, but it doesn't seem to work

```
    df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "FAILFAST") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true").option("sep", ' ').load("ds3.tsv")
    df.printSchema()
```

I see the following result when I do the "printSchema"

```
   root
    |-- student_id: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- subjects: string (nullable = true)
    |-- result: string (nullable = true)
```

When I do the following i.e. use the explode function:

```
    df.withColumn("subject", explode(col("subjects"))).select("student_id", "subject", "result").show(2)
```

I get the following exception:

```
    AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'explode(`subjects`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string;;\n'Project [student_id#10, subjects#11, results#12, explode(subjects#11) AS subject#30]\n+- AnalysisBarrier\n      +- Relation[student_id#10,subjects#11,result#12] csv\n"
```

I read somewhere that pyspark doesnt support ArrayType for strings.

Is it a good idea to write an UDF that would trim "[]" characters from both end of the "subjects" column values, then use "split" function and the use the "explode"?

Comment: It is clear, you have just a String for Subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second column is String, can be split, and then "explode" used:

```
val df = List(
  ("1001", "[physics, chemistry]", "pass"),
  ("1001", "[biology, math]", "fail"),
  ("1002", "[economics]", "pass"),
  ("1002", "[physics, chemistry]", "fail")
).toDF("student_id", "subjects", "result")

df
  .withColumn("clearedFromLeftBracket", expr("substring(subjects,2,length(subjects))"))
  .withColumn("clearedFromBrackets", expr("substring(clearedFromLeftBracket,1,length(clearedFromLeftBracket)-1)"))
  .withColumn("splitted", split($"clearedFromBrackets", ", "))
  .withColumn("subjectResult", explode($"splitted"))
  .drop("clearedFromLeftBracket", "clearedFromBrackets", "splitted","subjects")
```

Output:

```
+----------+------+-------------+
|student_id|result|subjectResult|
+----------+------+-------------+
|1001      |pass  |physics      |
|1001      |pass  |chemistry    |
|1001      |fail  |biology      |
|1001      |fail  |math         |
|1002      |pass  |economics    |
|1002      |fail  |physics      |
|1002      |fail  |chemistry    |
+----------+------+-------------+
```

Comment: For the uninitiated, the .show means a DF is not returned

Comment: it depends on taste, removed

Comment: Thanks a lot @pasha701, for the help! It worked perfectly...:)